# Server triggers client event twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, chat

hi I'm trying to develop simple chat app using socket.io and express.

My issue is: when user send message emit event to server and server broadcast to the rest clients- it happens twice 
That is all what I can't figured out: why 
socket.broadcast.emit('setMessage' fires twice in the browser setMessage

https://github.com/ntorbev/chat

any help will be appreciate

Comment: Welcome to StqackOverflow.please show us the code that is causing the issue.

Comment: hi is it ok to list my repo at the github which i have listed above

Comment: In your sockets.js file, I don't understand what sockets is in line 7 : "io.sockets.on" ? From http://socket.io/get-started/chat/ tutorial, just use io.on('connection', function(socket). On your handler 'newMessage', I would try io.emit on the client side, instead of socket.broadcast.emit and use that on the server side to dispatch the message to anyone except the sender

Comment: hi thanks for suggestion. "io.sockets.on" i think "io.on " is shorted but the same. "socket.broadcast.emit(" send the mess except to the sender. Anyway i tested you suggestions and doesn't fix the problem. "setMessage" handler is triggered twice again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in layout.jade, you're including chat.js twice

```
doctype html
html
    block head
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/site.css')
        script(type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js")
        script(type='text/javascript', src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/chat.js')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='/javascripts/chat.js')
    body
        header#banner
        //h1 Awesome Chat
        block content
        //footer Hope you enjoy your stay here
```

Comment: Hi 10x for replay
but i do it in reason 
socket.broadcast.emit will emit to all except the sender that why i'm doing this 
if i comment mentioned from you will be sender not showing what he/she type and the receiver will see twice message again. I have test it just to be sure

Comment: @ntorbev the issue is that you're including chat.js twice. I've edited my answer.

Comment: thanks Yuri. Very silly from my side that solve the broblem thank you very much